# Execute msix with administrator privileges and run script

Tags: maui

I am developing a Windows application with .NET MAUI and
I am building the msix with Visual Studio, as stated in the .NET MAUI documentation:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/windows/deployment/publish-visual-studio-folder

I don't know if it is possible for the MSIX installer to request administrator permissions to copy files to system32 during the installation, a dll written in C++ and a CLI .exe written in C++, or at the end of the installation run a script with administrator permissions to execute the CLI .exe.

Which is the way to go?

Comment: If the CLI  EXE has an embedded manifest resource that requires admin rights, then it will show the UAC prompt at startup and run with admi rights. For the MSIX, there should be a setting in whatever you use to build it to require admin rights, and to specify where files go.  If you need more, edit your question to provide more info about how you're building the MSIX -- I use InstallShield but others can help with Wix, etc.

Comment: @DaveS I think it has a better description now.

Comment: @DaveS any ideas?

Comment: Sorry, requiring admin rights is a toggle in the InstallShield UI, but you aren't using that.  There should be a parameter for it in the MSIX but you'll need to look for the UI or google for the parameter.  Same with the install location - in InstallShield the folders are filled with drag and drop.